# Is an element that is algebraic over $\mathbb{Q}$ algebraic over $\mathbb{Z}?$

Tags: abstract-algebra

In Fraleigh's *A First Course in Abstract Algebra*, it states that $\mathbb{C}$ is an extension field of $\mathbb{Q}$. This I understand, but then it states that since $\sqrt{2}$ is a zero of $x^2-2$, $\sqrt{2}$ is algebraic over $\mathbb{Q}$.  I'm not clear on why it matters that $\mathbb{C}$ is an extension field of $\mathbb{Q}$, since $\sqrt{2}$ is in $\mathbb{R}$.  In this case, is $\sqrt{2}$ algebraic over $\mathbb{Z}$, also?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It is algebraic over $\mathbb Z$, since the monic polynomial $x^2-2$ has integral coefficients, and hence belongs to $\mathbb Z[x]$.

Answer (score 1):

What Andres Mejia said is the reason $\sqrt{2}$ is algebraic over $\mathbb{Z}$, however judging by your question you might want to think whether "all elements that are algebraic over $\mathbb{Q}$ are also algebraic over $\mathbb{Z}$" is true or false. This is indeed very easy to think about.

Comment: If an element is algebraic over the rationals, then there it is a root of a polynomial with rational coefficients, but if we multiply out by e.g. the product of all denominators we get that it is also a root of a polynomial with integer coefficients, therefore it's algebraic over the integers. Is this correct?